# polymer 1.0 force array re-sorting/re-filtering

Tags: polymer-1.0

By default, dom-repeat arrays only re-filter and re-sort when the array itself is mutated, or the item itself changes property that correspond to its observer: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists.

Is there anyway to trigger sorting function when the sorting function itself change? For example, when you want to change from increasing order to decreasing order, a.k.a changing sorting function.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `render` on the `dom-repeat`.

From the [source code documentation](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/template/dom-repeat.html):

> In order to re-run the filter or sort functions based on changes to sub-fields
>   of `items`, the `observe` property may be set as a space-separated list of
>   `item` sub-fields that should cause a re-filter/sort when modified.  **If
>   the filter or sort function depends on properties not contained in `items`,
>   the user should observe changes to those properties and call `render` to update
>   the view based on the dependency change.**